# Vala How send result file.read to html

Tags: html, file, process, send, vala

i was wondering if anyone could give me pointers on how to send result from action glib.file.read to html.

example i want read file string.txt

```
File file = File.new_for_path ("string.txt");
try {
    FileInputStream @is = file.read ();
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream (@is);
    string line;

    while ((line = dis.read_line ()) != null) {
        stdout.printf ("%s\n", line);
    }
} catch (Error e) {
    stdout.printf ("Error: %s\n", e.message);
}

return 0;
```

and i want post result from this proses to file html, example index.html

help would be much appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a short example of how to write data to a file taken from the [GNOME Wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Vala/GIOSamples) (where you'll find more infos)

```
// an output file in the current working directory
var file = File.new_for_path ("index.html");

// creating a file and a DataOutputStream to the file
var dos = new DataOutputStream (file.create
    (FileCreateFlags.REPLACE_DESTINATION));

// writing a short string to the stream
dos.put_string ("this is the first line\n");
```

so you have to create your output file and create a DataOutputStream to it, and then, change your loop to write the data of your `"string.txt"` to `"index.html"`. In the end, it would look like this :

```
public static int main (string[] args) {
    File in_file = File.new_for_path ("string.txt");
    File out_file = File.new_for_path ("index.html");

    // delete the output file if it already exists (won't work otherwise if
    // it does)
    if (out_file.query_exists ()) {
        try {
            out_file.delete ();
        } catch (Error e) {
        stdout.printf ("Error: %s\n", e.message);
        }
    }

    try {
        // create your data input and output streams
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream (in_file.read ());
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream (out_file.create
            (FileCreateFlags.REPLACE_DESTINATION));

        string line;

        // write the data from string.txt to index.html line per line
        while ((line = dis.read_line ()) != null) {
            // you need to add a linebreak ("\n")
            dos.put_string (line+"\n");
        }
    } catch (Error e) {
        stdout.printf ("Error: %s\n", e.message);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @tuanpembual if that solved your problem click on the tick in the top left corner of my answer so that it becomes green (this is how stackoverflow works)